# Converting string to datetimeoffset in SQL Server and Postgresql

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, datetime, datetimeoffset

In SQL server I have a column that stores dates of this format:

> 2017-06-22T00:43:15+0300

as strings.

What I'm trying to do is cast these strings into actual datatimeoffset data in order to handle them as dates.

So far I have found multiple function for converting from datetimeoffset to other timestamp formats but none of these refer to strings.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql

Exactly the same problem arises on a postgresql database. The best I have managed to achieve so far is just truncate the timezone and convert the rest of the string into timestamp. Ideally, I would like not to use such a lossy transformation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Time Zone Offset` in Sql Server is represented like this

> [+|-] hh:mm:

In your data semicolon is missing in the `offset` part

```
DECLARE @stringtime VARCHAR(100)= '2017-06-22T00:43:15+0300'

SET @stringtime = Reverse(Stuff(Reverse(@stringtime), 3, 0, ':'))

SELECT Cast(@stringtime AS DATETIMEOFFSET(4))
```

**Result :** `2017-06-22 00:43:15.0000 +03:00`

Comment: This works! Thank you very much! Do you have any idea if there is something equivalent for postgresql?

Comment: @lacrima - Sorry I don't know `Postgresql`

Comment: Thank you -- this is the only working answer I could find to a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres :

```
to_timestamp('2017-06-22T00:43:15+0300', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

you can try using that postgres function.

Comment: I would like to keep all of the information from the timestamp. This will only keep year, month and day. Actually I would like to end up with exactly the same format but of type datetime, not string

Comment: @lacrima, try this to_timestamp('2017-06-22T00:43:15+0300', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') that's postgresql function

Comment: That's what I was doing until now but again I lose the timezone information